# viewing a document stored as BLOB datatype in document viewer?

Tags: php, upload, download, blob

i have a website in which when a user uploads a file or document it is stored in database in BLOB datatype.
Also there is a download link which retrives the document from database and lets the user download.
now i want this document to be viewed in a document viewer like google doc viewer,how do i go about doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

if you know the type of the file being downloaded you can use some thing like
Simple example:

```
$blob = "some data";

header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); // e.g. if a JPEG image
echo $blob;
```